# Periodic PaddingLayer

Tags: list-manipulation, neural-networks

The possible values to specify the `Padding` option of a `PaddingLayer` include a fixed value, `"Fixed"` for a repetition of the last value, and `"Reflected"` for a reflection of the input... but I see no way to achieve a periodic padding, which would be equally reasonable (and is possible *e.g.* in `ArrayPad`). Maybe this is hidden, or can be achieved in a Neural Network in some other way?

For concretenes, I'm looking for something like

```
PeriodicPaddingLayer[{{1,2}}]@Range@10
(*{10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very elegant approach but it does the job in your example and might get you started.

I am using

```
$Version
```

> "12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)"

Let's begin by getting the list you described using the `ArrayPad`

Let's create your list

```
list = Range@10;
```

and a pad

```
pad = {{1, 2}};
```

and the we do

```
exp1 = ArrayPad[list, pad, "Periodic"]
```

which yields

> {10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2}

In order to achieve the same thing using `PaddingLayer` the only way I could come up with is the following:

For a new pad given by

```
pad = {{1, 1}};
```

we run

```
exp2 = Fold[SubsetMap[Reverse, #1, #2] &, 
   PaddingLayer[pad, Padding -> "Fixed"]@list, {{1, 12}}] // 
  Append[#, 2] &
```

which gives

> {10., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 10., 1., 2}

Final comment: It is interesting to compare the time needed in each case.

```
exp1 = ArrayPad[list, pad, "Periodic"] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {2.*10^-6, {10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2}}

while on the other hand

```
exp2 = Fold[SubsetMap[Reverse, #1, #2] &, 
    PaddingLayer[pad, Padding -> "Fixed"]@list, {{1, 12}}] // 
   Append[#, 2] & // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.0060, {10., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 10., 1., 2}}

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a *layer* in the sense that I need an object that can be used within a larger neural network (created, with `NetGraph`, `NetChain`, etc). My current best is:

`
PeriodicPaddingLayer[n_Integer, m_Integer] :=
 NetGraph[
  {
   "left" -> PartLayer[;; m],
   "right" -> PartLayer[-n ;;],
   "catenate" -> CatenateLayer[]
   },
  {
   NetPort@"Input" -> {"left", "right"},
   {"right", NetPort@"Input", "left"} -> "catenate"
   }
  ]
`

which on my system works slightly faster than your version (though GPU compatibility is the real plus here).

Comment: @FidelI.Schaposnik thanks for that. Your seems to be a more programming approach in spirit